# Understanding the ordering of a python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Can someone please explain how python (v3.5) dictionaries are ordered?

```
data = {"John": 23, "Rick": 33, "Mary": 63, "Ron": 23, "Joel": 51}

for key in data:
        print("Your name is " + key + ", and you are also " + str(data[key]) + " years old.")
```

Actual output:

```
Your name is Rick, and you are also 33 years old.
Your name is Ron, and you are also 23 years old.
Your name is Mary, and you are also 63 years old.
Your name is John, and you are also 23 years old.
Your name is Joel, and you are also 51 years old.
```

Expected output (the order of the dictionary):

```
Your name is John, and you are also 23 years old.
Your name is Rick, and you are also 33 years old.
Your name is Mary, and you are also 63 years old.
Your name is Ron, and you are also 23 years old.
Your name is Joel, and you are also 51 years old.
```

Comment: what version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm learning from https://www.learnpython.org/ so I assume the newest. So v3.7? I tagged the post as 3.x.

Comment: What's the output of ``python -V`` this command, it might not be 3.7 because from python version >3.6 dict maintains insertion order.

Comment: Executing `print (sys.version)` in the link they provided, I got the version 3.5.2

Comment: Your python version is <= 3.5. Which doesn't remember the dictionary order!

Comment: interesting. so would it be recommended to avoid learning on this site given it's out of date nature?

Comment: @Mech, I added an answer that I hope could be a quick resolution for your question.

Comment: Not completely! You can look for updates of every new version on their official docs. As of now, the current stable version is 3.8 and it's hard to find a good tutorial on it.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: I'm not confident enough to post my own answer, but what current answers are missing is that in older Python versions (before they changed something to preserve insertion order) items where stored creating an hash table based on the key, and ordering the items with that criteria. This was done in order to speed up search: if the user accesses a specific key the hash is calculated and a binary search is done. As you can understand, the hash value order can  be different from insertion order or key alphabetical order. This is how I understood it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends upon the version of Python you are using.

### Before Python 3.6

Dictionaries used the ordering of the underlying hash function. Several types have salted hashes, so this means you obtain different order on each invocation.

### Python 3.6+

Dictionaries are insertion ordered, i.e., dictionaries remember the order of items inserted. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation):

> The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied upon

### Python 3.7

Guido van Rossum announced on that as of Python 3.7 dicts in [all Python implementations must preserve insertion order](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in a list, items stored in a dictionary aren't kept in any particular order; in fact, Python randomizes their left-to-right order to provide quick lookup. Keys provide the symbolic locations (not physical) of items in a dictionary.
If you think in a list as ordered collections of objects, you can think of dictionaries as unordered collections. The items are stored and fetched by key, instead of by positional offset :)