# Why would different characters impact the order of the output for this getPositions method?

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
class Solution(object):
    def getPositions(self, s):
        mapping = {}
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] not in mapping:
                mapping[s[i]] = [i]
            elif s[i] in mapping:
                mapping[s[i]].append(i)
        return mapping.values()
```

I would expect

```
getPositions("paper") == getPositions("title")
```

to be true but the output actually ends up being:

```
[[1], [0, 2], [4], [3]]   ==   [[1], [4], [0, 2], [3]]
```

Shouldn't the values of the character in the strings not matter in this method and what is causing the change in expected output?

Comment: Which version of Python? Dictionaries aren't semantically ordered data structures, they only retain insertion order since 3.7 (3.6 in CPython specifically).

Comment: Try `return list(mapping.values())` instead

Comment: Ah that's it @JonSG dict_values objects aren't equal even if the values _are_ in the same order. `Solutions().getPositions("paper") != Solutions().getPositions("paper")`, let alone `"title"`. The reference to _"the order of the values differ"_ was a bit of a mislead.

Comment: `mapping.values()` doesn't return a list, it returns a generator (actually a "view"). So you can't compare them for equality.

Comment: @KellyBundy Maybe -- it's long since time for LeetCode to change its Python default to 3.x.

Comment: Oh I was right after all, dupe of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62869237/3001761 then. You could use a `collections.OrderedDict` to get retained insertion order (and _semantic_ ordering).